# How to spy on interceptor class with mockito in quarkus test

Tags: mockito, quarkus, interceptor, spy

In unit test I try to spy on following intceptor class, on method `org.acme.LoggingInterceptor#log(java.lang.String)`

```
package org.acme;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

import io.quarkus.arc.Priority;
import io.quarkus.logging.Log;

@Logging
@Priority(10)
@Interceptor
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoggingInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    Object log(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        log("inside LoggingInterceptor @AroundInvoke");
        return ctx.proceed();
    }

    public void log(String message) {
        Log.info(message);
    }
}
```

I tried with quarkus test by `@InjectSpy` and also by creating spy directly in the test by `Mockito.spy(..)` Both fails

1st: fails already when creating the test, error: Invalid use of io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectSpy - could not resolve the bean of type: org.acme.LoggingInterceptor. Offending field is loggingInterceptor of test class class org.acme.LoggingInterceptorTest1_Subclass

```
@QuarkusTest
public class LoggingInterceptorTest1 {

//FIXME fails with: Invalid use of io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectSpy - could not resolve the bean of type: org.acme.LoggingInterceptor. Offending field is loggingInterceptor of test class class org.acme.LoggingInterceptorTest1_Subclass 
    @InjectSpy
    LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor;

    @Test
    public void test() ...
```

2nd: fails with: Wanted but not invoked: loggingInterceptor.log();

```
@QuarkusTest
public class LoggingInterceptorTest2 {

    @Test
    public void testAroundInvoke() {
        LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = Mockito.spy(LoggingInterceptor.class);

        serviceMethodWithInterceptor();

        ArgumentCaptor<String> logMessageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        Mockito.verify(loggingInterceptor).log(logMessageCaptor.capture());

        //FIXME fails with: Wanted but not invoked: loggingInterceptor.log(<Capturing argument>);
        assertEquals("inside LoggingInterceptor @AroundInvoke", logMessageCaptor.getValue());
    }
```

Sample project here: https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/tree/spy_on_interceptor

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that's wrong here is that the interceptor is annotated `@ApplicationScoped`. Quoting the CDI specification:

> Instances of interceptors are dependent objects of the bean instance they intercept.

Newer versions of Quarkus will actually fail the deployment when such incorrect interceptor exists, to satisfy this rule:

> If an interceptor declares any scope other than `@Dependent`, the container automatically detects the problem and treats it as a definition error.

Second, the `@InjectMock` and `@InjectSpy` mechanism only works for normal scoped beans, as described in https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus_mock (this is because for normal scoped beans, what gets injected is not an "actual" instance, but a client proxy, which is responsible for looking up the instance -- and that is also how mocking is done).

Since interceptors are never normal scoped, `@InjectMock` and `@InjectSpy` can't work for them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. So this means there is no way to spy on interceptors, right?